# Amazon image not uploading from Server Production Mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, passenger, digital-ocean

I am using `amazon S3` service for uploading images for my Rails app.

I have hosted my app in Digital Ocean.

I am running app with two ip's,

`ip (default port 80)`  - passenger settings are done properly

`ip:3004` - running in the server(`RAILS_ENV=production rails s -p 3004`) without passenger setting

The images are uploading if i use port ( web_ip:3004 ). But when I do with port no 80 the images are not saving instead giving error:

> "We're sorry, but something went wrong.".

Can you please suggest me how to resolve it or setting with passenger...!